# Click event of UIButton is not getting fired

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, xib

I made a simple app in which i am loading different `.xib` on each orientation,

I have two xib's `Portxib` and `Landxib`, in both xibs, i dragged a button and assigned a

tag value to it as `1` in both xib's.

and i wrote this code in my `viewDidLoad`

```
UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here is the selector method,

```
-(void)BtnClick:(id)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"BtnClick");
    }
```

Click event of UIButton is not getting fired...

OR

Is there any other way to call the same method of button from both the orientation ??

**EDIT :**

`.h file`

[image]
`.m file`
[image]

Comment: you can try adding the code in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation to get fired in both orientations

Comment: You can try my answer to call same method from both XIB's.

Comment: is your button clicked event fired on any one orientation ?? either in landscape or portrait ??

Comment: no.. it is not getting fired, i have not created any outlet or action connection using (ctrl+dragging) in my .h file using file owner in xib.. because i am giving object name to button via tag property,i am not sure but i think i am right..

Comment: is your `changeOrientation` method call before `UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];` ??

Comment: yes `changeOrientation` is getting called but click event is not getting called.. do i need to connect `IBAction` event to button

Comment: yes, You can connect `IBAction` event to button. That way is working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure...

1. Button is placed in root view in `xib` as you are finding it in `self.view` OR make sure it is placed in correct view and use that view with `viewWithTag`
2. You have assigned tag **1**, so just make sure no other control within
   same view have tag 1 other wise button will not be recognized by tag. If this is going to be your case then just change tag of button to very unusual number for that view like 999 or any thing else and test.

**EDIT**

I am feeling like you view is not getting recognized at `viewDidLoad` where you have setup your code. So just comment out that code in `viewDidLoad` and shift in your **changeOrientation** method after loading nib.

```
-(void)changeOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];


    if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PortraitXib" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LandscapeXib" owner:self options:nil];
    }

    //Adding this code here makes sense that nib is loaded and after that we are recognizing button from loaded view of nib.
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have created class without xib and added two xib one for portrait and other for landscape, in both the xib there is a button with same tag.. but still click event is not getting fired..

Comment: Just asking you to make sure not to have any other control in xib with tag 1 except your button.

Comment: yeah only button has tag 1

Comment: Then make sure about the parent view of the button. if is under direct  root view then your code will work. if is inside some other view then it will not recognize it.

Comment: I think that xib view is not self.view

Comment: Check out this link i have uploaded my project...  http://www.mediafire.com/?jtgwo4ydllizp0r

Comment: There is only one button in both the xib.. with tag value `1`

Comment: check my post. print those

Comment: I have not created any outlet or action connection using (ctrl+dragging) in my `.h` file using file owner.. because i am giving object name to button via tag property

Comment: Please look at my updated answer and try this. I have tested your code it was not working then I shifted code inside changeOrientation and it's working now :)

Answer (score 5):

In header file add

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
```

reference this btn from your xib files.

Here in your case the btn you are using is not referenced from the xib files so the method is not firing

```
-(IBAction)BtnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"BtnClick");
}
```

make the function as IBAction and reference this from nib btn.
In this case you no need to addtarget explicitly.

If you are not adding the button in the nib, then dont forget to init and addsubview to the view

You can see this tutorial http://www.idev101.com/learn/interface_builder_connections.html

**EDIT**  Check what is printing?

```
     for (UIButton *but in [self.view subviews])
     {
            NSLog("but.tag %d",but.tag);
            if(but.tag==1)// compare for same row elements
            {
            NSLog("Button Added");

              [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
      }
```

Comment: log shows btn.tag is `1` and shows `Button Added` but still click event is not getting fired.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button like this.
Add this to you didLoad method

```
 UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [aButton setTag:1];
  [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [aView addSubview:aButton];
}

// then ...

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
  NSLog(@"Button %d clicked.", [button tag]);
}
```